# Set relationship bidirectional in SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am curious whether it's possible to set relations bidirectional in code in SQL Server. If that's not possible, where in SSMS can I edit the relationships?

Currently I have the following piece of code that sets the relationship, but when I load my SQL Model in Power BI it's been recognized as a unidirectional relation.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE NAME = 'Ad_DIM_Bezit' AND xtype = 'U')
ALTER TABLE Ad_Feiten WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Ad_Feiten_DIM_Bezit] FOREIGN KEY([%ObjectKey])
REFERENCES Ad_DIM_Bezit ([%ObjectKey])
ALTER TABLE Ad_Feiten CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Ad_Feiten_DIM_Bezit]
```

Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: Foreign keys are *constraints*, not relations. They don't have "direction", they say that a set of values from a single row should match a set of values in another table.

Comment: I suspect the real question is about *Power BI*, and whether or not it can navigate both ways in its model?

Comment: Also, you don't set it anywhere in SSMS; SSMS is just an application to communicates with SQL Server. All the `CONSTRAINTS`, objects, etc, are defined in the SQL Server, not SSMS. YOun don't *have* to use SSMS to create a Foreign Key; you could use any IDE/CLI that communicates with SQL Server,.

Comment: No not exactly. when I load this entire model in PowerBI it shows an unidirectional relationship, and manually I can set this two bidirectional in PowerBI. Though there should be something in SMSS to do this beforehand, instead of always after loading in QlikView/PBI, etc doing it manually afterwards

Comment: Ok, thanks, then I will stop looking for it there!